# Switch between sound profiles iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications

I have found no way that iPhone is able to do what I need here. I have iOS 6.x (jailbroken).

I would like to set 3-4 Sounds themes (basic feature of all Nokia). Example I need:

- **Normal**: vibrance ok, sounds normal
- **High tone**: volume up
- **Silence**: vibrance ok but only with a single low tone to alert of SMS, email etc
- **Dead**: no vibrance, no sounds.

Is there any app or somethign that let me set this 4 profiles?

I have not been able to find a way to do this with either jailbreak tweaks nor with the built in iOS.

*(Please note I know I can switch between silence and do not disturb, but I want to personalize this profiles, also I need high tone profile)*

Comment: I can't comment on jailbroken apps, as I haven't jailbroken since 2008. However, I can confirm that there is no way to replicate the Nokia-style sound profiles on iOS. You can turn the ringer volume up for High Tone, and you can toggle vibrate on and off in Settings. I understand this is not the same. This is something that frustrated me when I switched from Nokia to iPhone but have since come to appreciate the simplicity of the vibrate switch.

Comment: @bispymusic, very well put. I have (and still am) observing one individual switch from BB to iPhone and another from Android to iPhone. The main thing I have noticed (particularly with the x-BB user) is that they got used to the (over)-complexity of particularly the BB system. Overtime, the appreciation for simplicity comes.

Comment: Anyone know if this will change with iOS 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SBProfiles will let you set up profiles for lots of settings on your phone - including sound and vibration. Here's a YouTube video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DlGjZ6UACFs

Intelliborn once had an app called MyProfiles (http://intelliborn.com/myprofiles.html) but it has been discontinued and only works on iOS 4

Comment: Yes SBProfiles is what it get closer to my question. The problem with SBprofiles is that you can't change the ring for the various profiles... Or can you?

Comment: I don't think you can change the ring. Wish someone would develop an app to make it easy like the old Nokia phones.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can! But now sbsettings does not support IOS 7 yes. But earlier versions there is no problem.

Comment: The OP is on iOS 6, so you should provide some more detailed information on how this can be accomplished.